# Exclude REST API request based on the IPs

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, triggered-send, exclusion-script

I desire to discard certain requests coming from a specific IP. 
I'm using dynamic emails through AMPScript and Triggered Sends+Data Extensions.

I'm able to discard certain requests when are not matching a row from the DE or the payload is missing a field.

However for discard certain request coming from an IP is something I can't figure out how to solve it. I have requested help from the Support but apart from a call they were not able to help me out.

Do you know if there's any variable from the sendable Data Extension referred to the IP?

Comment: Why exactly do you need to do this? Your API-credentials should secure the REST-API from unauthorized usage, not a filter afterwards.

Comment: As my answer is correct and only doesn't work as you aren't an admin and I even proposed a possible workaround, please mark my answer as accepted so others can see there is a correct answer to your question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is no possibility to forbid access for certain IPs. However you could create multiple API-Integrations in AppCenter, where you only grant the access needed by the user you give the credentials to. For the already created integrations you can revoke access to certain features under "Data Access".

[image: AppCenter - Data Access]

Comment: There is no built-in way of restricting access then. As my answer provided all the information on current possibilities to restriction access in marketing cloud, I'd appreciate it if you mark it as accepted so others can see there is a correct answer. If you need such a feature I suggest creating a request in the Salesforce Success IdeaExchange. **Workaround:** For now you could add some kind of key/signed value to the attributes passed to the send and written to the data extension. In the email you can then check this via AMPscript and throw an error if this hasn't been signed with your key.